# how can I process each line or word in the text file using matlab?

Tags: matlab, text

How can I process each line or word in a text file using MATLAB?

The contents of the text file are in this format, where each line consists of two names with a number attached with an underscore:

```
 Abdel_Madi_Shabneh_0001 Dean_Barker_0001
 Abdel_Madi_Shabneh_0001 Giancarlo_Fisichella_0001
 Abdel_Madi_Shabneh_0001 Mikhail_Gorbachev_0001
 Abdul_Rahman_0001 Portia_de_Rossi_0001
 Abel_Pacheco_0001 Jong_Thae_Hwa_0002
 Abel_Pacheco_0002 Jean-Francois_Lemounier_0001
 Afton_Smith_0001 Dwayne_Wade_0001
 Ahmad_Jbarah_0001 James_Comey_0001
```

and I'd like to reformat the content to make it like this, in other words but them into cell of nX2 dimension so I can each them easily:

```
'Abdel_Madi_Shabneh_0001' 'Dean_Barker_0001';
'Abdel_Madi_Shabneh_0001' 'Giancarlo_Fisichella_0001';
'Abdel_Madi_Shabneh_0001' 'Mikhail_Gorbachev_0001';
'Abdul_Rahman_0001'       'Portia_de_Rossi_0001';
'Abel_Pacheco_0001'       'Jong_Thae_Hwa_0002';
'Abel_Pacheco_0002'       'Jean-Francois_Lemounier_0001';
'Afton_Smith_0001'        'Dwayne_Wade_0001';
'Ahmad_Jbarah_0001'       'James_Comey_0001';
```

Is there a way how can I do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strsplit`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) to split your strings on the specified delimiter:

```
DataCell = strplit(data);
```

Note that it is not required to specify the delimiter in this case, since whitespace is the default.

Comment: But it is still I have to add the comma manually for each line in the text

Comment: @AlaaAlwaisy what do you mean? Your question asks how to transform the given input into an `nx2` array. Where do commas come in?

Comment: I mean the format of the input data it has to be some think like this in order to deal with it as a string:
'Abdel_Madi_Shabneh_0001' 'Dean_Barker_0001'
'Abdel_Madi_Shabneh_0001' 'Giancarlo_Fisichella_0001'
'Abdel_Madi_Shabneh_0001' 'Mikhail_Gorbachev_0001'

Comment: And my question is how can I add these commas for each line in a text?